# What algorithm can be used to diff image files?

Tags: diff

Note that I'm not asking to create a "visual diff" of image files.  I'm asking if there's a Unix command-line diff/patch utility that works well for image files.

So far, I have tried out bsdiff and xdelta on two image files.  One file is a 8000x8000 picture and used Gimp's "random noise" renderer.  The other is the same picture with some blue lines drawn on it for a somewhat realistic test.

Here's my results:

```
$ time xdelta3 -e -s 1.png 2.png xdelta.patch

real    0m1.222s
user    0m1.106s
sys     0m0.114s

$ time bsdiff 1.png 2.png bsdiff.patch

real    0m20.860s
user    0m20.694s
sys     0m0.169s

$ ls -l 1.png 2.png xdelta.patch bsdiff.patch 
-rw-r--r-- 1 mardok mardok 6278160 May 20 20:21 1.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 mardok mardok 6669305 May 20 20:32 2.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 mardok mardok 6682740 May 20 21:06 bsdiff.patch
-rw-r--r-- 1 mardok mardok 6678609 May 20 21:05 xdelta.patch
```

Neither tool is well-suited for the job because the patches are bigger than the images themselves.  bsdiff is especially not suited for the job because it took 20 seconds.

So, is there a different kind of algorithm that can be used to diff images?

EDIT: I just ran another test, but this time saved the images in Gimp's native .xcf format.  The results are better.

```
$ ls -l 1.xcf 2.xcf xcf.bsdiff xcf.xdelta 
-rw-r--r-- 1 mardok mardok 54693130 May 20 21:38 1.xcf
-rw-r--r-- 1 mardok mardok 53575879 May 20 21:38 2.xcf
-rw-r--r-- 1 mardok mardok  2758826 May 20 21:39 xcf.bsdiff
-rw-r--r-- 1 mardok mardok  3912197 May 20 21:41 xcf.xdelta
```

The xcf files are five times bigger than the PNG's, but the diff's are much smaller.  So, it looks like PNG's are a pain to diff.  However, I would really like to know if there's a utility that can handle PNG's, JPG's, TIFF's, or other mainstream image file formats.

EDIT2: JPEG's now:

```
$ ls -l 1.jpg 2.jpg jpg.bsdiff jpg.xdelta 
-rw-r--r-- 1 mardok mardok 2134569 May 20 21:49 1.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 mardok mardok 4509765 May 20 21:49 2.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 mardok mardok 3417896 May 20 21:50 jpg.bsdiff
-rw-r--r-- 1 mardok mardok 3917899 May 20 21:50 jpg.xdelta
```

I didn't post the time, but bsdiff took an unusually short time to create a diff on the JPEG files.  And this is the first diff that managed to produce a smaller result for one of the images.  However, it's still not good enough because the patch needs to be noticeably smaller than both files.

CORRECTION: bsdiff took an unusually short time because the JPEG's are small.  Whoops.

EDIT3: And just for complete-ness's sake, here's the results for TIFF files:

```
$ ls -l 1.tiff 2.tiff tiff.xdelta tiff.bsdiff 
-rw-r--r-- 1 mardok mardok 10182924 May 20 21:56 1.tiff
-rw-r--r-- 1 mardok mardok 11069486 May 20 21:56 2.tiff
-rw-r--r-- 1 mardok mardok 11077784 May 20 21:57 tiff.bsdiff
-rw-r--r-- 1 mardok mardok 11054104 May 20 21:56 tiff.xdelta
```

They both had the same kind of results as the PNG tests.  They're not well suited for the job.

All-in-all, your typical binary diff should not be used on image files.  What algorithm should be used instead?

Comment: Not that I know of....but I'm glad you're not trying to cheat at "Spot the difference" type games in the kids comic pages :)

Comment: i don't know much about images.  so this might be way off.  but what about the mpeg3/4 stuff?  don't they start with an image, then 'diff' it constantly to make a movie?

Comment: I've reworded the question to ask what algorithm should be used instead.  Is that a better suit for SO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any general binary diff tool is going to have problems with compressed data. The reason is that at a byte level, the compressed data can change significantly even with small changes in the input data.

When you take that random noise image and draw a few lines on it, the compression used in the PNG file is going to make a completely different output file. There's pretty much no way around this.

In order to do effective deltas on image files, you would need to use a tool that decompresses both images, compares them pixel by pixel, and creates a list of differences. The patch program would read the source image, and the list of differences, and create a new resulting image.

One problem you may run into with the above approach is that since image compression is non-deterministic, you may not get the same *compressed* bytes in the resulting image as the original second image. If all goes well you should get the same *uncompressed* image, but that doesn't help if you are trying to verify digital signatures of files, for example.